# PHP Form Response - When HTML form is submitted the PHP returned is plain text

Tags: php, html, xampp

I have a simple HTML form and a PHP response.
The PHP returns plain text upon submission.
I am using the most current version of XAMPP and ensured that I have the most current version of PHP. All files are saved in the htdocs folder of XAMPP.
I'm lost, as other simpler PHP files run without issues.
Any suggestions on what to look for or to try?
HTML FORM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="Response.php" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required><br>

        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" required><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required><br>

        <label for="color">Favorite Color:</label>
        <input type="color" name="color" required><br>

        <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other<br>

        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <select name="country" required>
            <option value="USA">United States</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select><br>

        <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
        <textarea name="comments" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Response</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form Response</h1>
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $age = $_POST["age"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $color = $_POST["color"];
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        $country = $_POST["country"];
        $comments = $_POST["comments"];
        
        // Verify that all fields were populated and data was correctly entered
        if (!empty($name) && is_numeric($age) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($color) && !empty($gender) && $country !== 'Select Country' && !empty($comments)) {
            echo "<p><strong>Name:</strong> $name</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Age:</strong> $age</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Favorite Color:</strong> <span style='background-color: $color; color: white;'>$color</span></p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Gender:</strong> $gender</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Country:</strong> $country</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Comments:</strong> $comments</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Error: Please make sure all fields are correctly filled.</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Error: Invalid request method.</p>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really. You just referred him to an ocean of Apache Directives when all he needed was a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Actually, that helped to solve my issue. I feel dumb, being that the solution was so simple.  For some reason, I was accessing the file via local file access and not using the webserver URL.  @Don'tPanic thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... make sure that `Content-Type` is set to `text/html` if your goal is to return an html page.

You are getting a plain text response because you are not setting the `Content-Type` header at all.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// rest of your PHP code
?>
```

Add this `header` function at the beginning of your PHP file to explicitly set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`.